# Is there a way to keep the Azure DataFactory from reporting a pipeline as failed when only one activity has failed?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have created a pipeline in Azure DataFactory that comprises of multiple activities, some of which are used as fallbacks if certain activities fail. Unfortunately, the pipeline is always reported as "failed" in the monitor tab, even if the fallback activities succeed. Can pipelines be set to appear as "succeeded" in the monitoring tab even if one or more activities fail?

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi jaysc, does AbhishekKhandave's answer answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can pipelines be set to appear as "succeeded" in the monitoring tab
> even if one or more activities fail

There are 3 ways to handle this mechanism

1. Try Catch block This approach renders pipeline succeeds, if Upon Failure path succeeds.

[image]

2. Do If Else block This approach renders pipeline fails, even if Upon Failure path succeeds.

[image]

3. Do if Skip Else block This approach renders pipeline succeeds, if Upon Failure path succeeds.

[image]

Using above approach you can get success status even if one or more activities fail.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-failure-error-handling